R function does not return NA when it should
I developed an R function to find a given pattern and check for before and after that pattern, I asked the function to return NA, when the pattern is not found, but now the function returns 0000000 instead of NA when there is no pattern.
GCbackbone <- function(x,pattern = "GAGTA",befor=1,after=1) {
  match <- regexpr(pattern,x)
  if(match[1]==-1){
    return(c(NA,NA))
  }
  n <- nchar(pattern)
  af <- substr(x,match[1]+n+after-1,n+match[1]+after-1)
  bef <- substr(x,match[1]-befor,match[1]-befor)
  return(c(bef,af))
}
vec <- myDataFrame$squence
befor1 <- sapply(vec,GCbackbone,befor = 1,after = 1) |> unname() |>
  apply(2,paste0,collapse = "")
befor2 <- sapply(vec,GCbackbone,befor = 2,after = 2) |> unname() |> 
  apply(2,paste0,collapse = "")
befor3 <- sapply(vec,GCbackbone,befor = 3,after = 5) |> unname() |> 
  apply(2,paste0,collapse = "")
befor4 <- sapply(vec,GCbackbone,befor = 4,after = 6) |> unname() |> 
  apply(2,paste0,collapse = "")
befor6 <- sapply(vec,GCbackbone,befor = 6,after = 9) |> unname() |> 
  apply(2,paste0,collapse = "")
befor7 <- sapply(vec,GCbackbone,befor = 7,after = 10) |> unname() |> 
  apply(2,paste0,collapse = "")
befor8 <- sapply(vec,GCbackbone,befor = 8,after = 11) |> unname() |> 
  apply(2,paste0,collapse = "")


res1 <- as.numeric(befor1 %in% c("GC","CG"))
res2 <- as.numeric(befor2 %in% c("GC","CG"))
res3 <- as.numeric(befor3 %in% c("GC","CG"))
res4 <- as.numeric(befor4 %in% c("GC","CG"))
res6 <- as.numeric(befor6 %in% c("GC","CG"))
res7 <- as.numeric(befor7 %in% c("GC","CG"))
res8 <- as.numeric(befor8 %in% c("TG","GT"))

myDataFrame$GCresult <- cbind(res1,res2,res3,res4,res6,res7,res8) |> apply(1,paste0,collapse = "")

First 6 rows of myDataFrame:
dput(head(myDataFrame))

structure(list(subject.acc.ver = c("KP036503.1", "KP036502.1", 
"MW791835.", "MZ461455.1", "MZ461454.1", "MZ461453.1"), s2m = c("GGCCACGCCGAGTAGGATCGAGGGTA", 
"GGCCACGCTGAGTAGGATCGAGGGTA", "GGCCACGACGAGTAGGATCGAGGGTA", "GGCCACRCCGAGTAGGATCGAGGGTA", 
"GGCAAAGCCGAGTAGGATCGAGGGTA", "GGCCACGCCGAGTAGGATCGAGGAAA"), 
    GCresult = c("1111111", "0111111", "1011111", "1101111", 
    "1110011", "1111100")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")


Can you add a sample of "MyDataFrame", or of the resulting vectors?

1 KP696543.1 GGCCACGCCGAGTAGGATCGAGGGTA 1111111
2 KP046442.1 GGCCACGCTGAGTAGGATCGAGGGTA 0111111
3 MW5617835. GGCCACGACGAGTAGGATCGAGGGTA 1011111
4 MZ4634235.1 GGCCACRCCGAGTAGGATCGAGGGTA 1101111
5 MZ461454.1 GGCAAAGCCGAGTAGGATCGAGGGTA 1110011
6 MZ461453.1 GGCCACGCCGAGTAGGATCGAGGAAA 1111100

That does not help. What is the output to dput(head(MyDataFrame)? Edit your post and add the content there with code formatting.

structure(list(subject.acc.ver = c("KP036503.1", "KP036502.1",
"MW791835.", "MZ461455.1", "MZ461454.1", "MZ461453.1"), s2m = c("GGCCACGCCGAGTAGGATCGAGGGTA",
"GGCCACGCTGAGTAGGATCGAGGGTA", "GGCCACGACGAGTAGGATCGAGGGTA", "GGCCACRCCGAGTAGGATCGAGGGTA",
"GGCAAAGCCGAGTAGGATCGAGGGTA", "GGCCACGCCGAGTAGGATCGAGGAAA"),
GCresult = c("1111111", "0111111", "1011111", "1101111",
"1110011", "1111100")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

regexpr is vectorized, so if you do match <- regexpr(pattern,x) you get a vector but you test for a scalar with match[1].

Maybe this is what you're after, using str_locate to find the start and end of the pattern
library(stringr)

GCbackbone <- function(vec, pattern = "GAGTA", bf=1, af=1) sapply(vec, \(x){ 
  m <- str_locate(x, pattern)
  if(any(is.na(m))) c(NA, NA)
  c(before=substr(x, m[,"start"] - (bf - 1) - 1, m[,"start"] - 1), 
    after=substr(x, m[,"end"] + 1, m[,"end"] + (af - 1) + 1))}, USE.NAMES=F)

GCbackbone(myDataFrame$s2m, "GCCG", 2, 1)
       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
before "AC" NA   NA   NA   "AA" "AC"
after  "A"  NA   NA   NA   "A"  "A"

Keep in mind that it only considers the first match within a string. Use str_locate_all to get all matches.
